# Как работает lstrcpy?

Tags: c, winapi

Как работает функция `lstrcpy` (*WinAPI*) на уже заполненный массив? Перезаписывает старые данные, или смещает их вправо, а потом заносит новые? Если второй вариант, то получается, нельзя заносить данные этой функцией в уже заполненный массив?

Comment: Ничего она не смещает. Просто копирует строку из одного места в другое. [В MSDN написано, что использовать эту функцию не следует вообще](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms647490(v=vs.85).aspx). Просто напишите, что вы хотите сделать, и почему именно таким образом, и вам тут подскажут. Потом, тег `C++` неправильный. Это относится к `C`.

Comment: А что, из С++ нельзя использовать его?

Comment: @bukkojot, не рекомендуется использовать в C++ из C то, для чего есть специальные классы или методы. И вообще между современным C++ и C общего — одна буква в названии.

Answer (score 7):

По аналогии с обычной `strcpy` она берёт вторую строку и записывает поверх первой.
Т. е. по первому указателю получается копия второй строки.

Comment: Дополню: если не хватит места в буфере, то результат непредсказуем по типичным для C причинам. Если блоки данных пересекаются, то результат непредсказуем из-за алгоритма самой функции - из [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms647490(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Да, я по этому и задал вопрос, что в мсдн у меня эта строка вызвала недопонимание. Что значит - если блоки данных пересекутся? Каких данных? То есть, все таки, если в массиве что-то есть, то уже нельзя применять эту функцию на этот буфер, т.к. результат непредсказуем?

Comment: Что значит, что блоки пересекаются? Например, если у вас есть `char src[] = "asdfghjkl"` и вы решили копировать `lstrcpy(src, src+2)`. Т.е. в процессе копирования одни и те же места в памяти будут выступать так в роли источника, так и в роли приемника.